# how to use front camera using flex4

Tags: android, actionscript-3, apache-flex, camera, flex4

I have developed simple camera application for Android mobile using flex 4. The problem is , when I run that application it uses the rear camera. It's not using the front camera. How can I change the camera. I need to use front side camera for this application , kindly help me .

```
var camera:Camera = Camera.getCamera(cameraIndex.toString());
if (camera)
{
    var ui: UIComponent = new UIComponent();
    var localVideoDisplay: Video = new Video(180, 135);
    localVideoDisplay.attachCamera(camera);
    ui.addChild(localVideoDisplay);                     
    cameraGroup.addChild(ui);
}
```

this is the code I have used in my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
function getCamera( position:String ):Camera
{
    var camera:Camera;
    var cameraCount:uint = Camera.names.length;
    for ( var i:uint = 0; i < cameraCount; ++i )
    {
        camera = Camera.getCamera( String(i) );
        if ( camera.position == position ) 
            return camera;
    }
    return Camera.getCamera();
}
```

Use  `getCamera(CameraPosition.FRONT)`

Comment: when I try this code, It shows white screen, both camera is not working. can you give me any suggestions for solve this problem please.

Comment: which flex sdk version are you using.Probably this link will help you:-http://www.riagora.com/2010/07/android-air-and-the-camera/