# Adobe AIR AS3 - Front facing camera

Tags: actionscript-3, air, flash-cs5

I am currently using the code shown below to access and display the camera on an Android device. It works fine but instead of accessing the standard camera I would like to access the front facing camera. How can I modify the code below to do this ? Thanks in advance.

```
var cam:Camera = Camera.getCamera(); 
var vid:Video = new Video(); 
vid.attachCamera(cam); 
addChild(vid);
if (cam != null) 
{ 
    cam.addEventListener(StatusEvent.STATUS, statusHandler); 
    vid = new Video(); 
    vid.attachCamera(cam); 
} 
function statusHandler(event:StatusEvent):void 
{ 
    if (!cam.muted) 
    { 
        vid.width = cam.width; 
        vid.height = cam.height; 
        addChild(vid); 

    } 
    cam.removeEventListener(StatusEvent.STATUS, statusHandler); 
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10629141/645918 how about this answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pass the Cam's Index value for your front camera in your `Camera.getCamera();`, like:

```
var camIndex:String = "1"; 
var cam:Camera = Camera.getCamera(camIndex);
```

If the above modification doesn't change anything try changing the value of camIndex to "0", "2", "3" it depends on which index your front camera is registered. Try it!

Answer (score 0):

The best way to get front camera on both android and on ios devices while developing application with Adobe Air is;

```
protected var _camera:Camera = null;    
_camera = getCamera(CameraPosition.FRONT);
```

and then

```
private function getCamera(position:String):Camera
    {
      for (var i:uint = 0; i < Camera.names.length; ++i)
      {
        var cam:Camera = Camera.getCamera(String(i));
        if (cam.position == position) return cam;
      }
      return Camera.getCamera();
    }
```

By passing camera name sometime not working especially in ios based devices.